# Can't get access to HDD at all

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, arch-linux

I cannot get access to my internal HDD without sudo or root, tried mounting it on `/media/disk`, `/home/username/data` and `/dev/data` but it did not make a difference.

I want to use it for storing my files and projects

These commands also didn't fix anything:

```
sudo chown -R username *
sudo chgrp -R username *
```

`/etc/fstab` content:

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/mapper/main-root
UUID=6f686dda-1424-4a42-8b90-6ed6c4951640       /               ext4            rw,relatime     0 1

# /dev/sda1
UUID=2FB9-EDC9          /boot           vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=as>

# /dev/mapper/main-swap
UUID=6063f915-0ab8-4c6c-b90e-819593495025       none            swap            defaults        0 0

#datadisk /dev/sdb
UUID=5e438a5d-8985-455c-a05d-5460779bbf14       /home/username/data       ext4            defaults,user   0 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -alh` of the root directory of the drive?

Comment: `
total 8.0K
d-wx--x--x  2 root   root   4.0K Jan  4 18:00 .
drwx------ 13 adobug adobug 4.0K Jan  4 20:38 ..

`

Comment: Your comments indicate it is working in another machine so I removed my answer as it does not apply.

Comment: Can you clarity: (1) Do you have access is root? (2) Since you show the 'ls' output, do you mean you do not have *write* access? (3) You are talking about `/dev/sdb' shown above? (4) Was the drive previously used externally using an enclosure?

Comment: @adobug - Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  Any information contained within an answer cannot be considered when submitting an answer.  I assume the user you are using is adobug?  Doesn't matter the root directory is owned by root not adobug if I am reading the unformatted output correctly.  **If adobug  needs sudo access use root to edit the sudo file.**

Answer (score 0):

I tried these commands that I found in an old forum post:

```
# chgrp storage /media/disk
# chmod 775 /media/disk
# gpasswd -a user_name storage
```

and it still did not work so I changed the second command to chmod 777 instead of 775 and after a reboot, it worked!

Comment: chmod 775 also works :)